# "The process has forked..." Error while using tm package in R

Tags: r, tm

I installed the `tm package` in `R` to do some text mining analysis. After creating a corpus I wanted to use the `tm_map()` function, which throws the following error message:

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().Break on
```

Anybody an idea why this message turns up?

Here's more code for clarification:

```
> require(tm)
Lade nötiges Paket: tm
> a <-Corpus(VectorSource(chi2014_df$text))
> a
A corpus with 70 text documents
> a <-tm_map(a,tolower)
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on
```

I'm using R 3.0.1 GUI 1.61 Snow Leopard build (6492)  on OSX 10.7.5

---

Comment: Does the same thing happen with the package's examples with the built in data sets?

Comment: Ok the later problem is solved by the snowball package !